# toggleGot is not a function

Tags: javascript, react-native

when I press the TouchableOpacity I get an error 'toggleGot is not a function. (in 'toggleGot(todo.id)', 'toggleGot' is undefined)
error

when onPress it supposed to toggle the .got: between true and false.

I am having trouble locating the problem I looked over the other areas of the code everything seems in order.  I am wondering if it has to do with passing the todo.id twice. Am i possibly supposed to make two components out of that and import?  Would like to understand not just solve.

I have looked over every bit, looked for spelling errors syntax errors, forgotten imports.  I cant sniff it out.
I was just curious if the error is here as I expect.. I looked for syntax errors everywhere else.  I just am thinking maybe theres a rule here im missing about bind this  clashing that I am missing.

```
// COMPONENT
const TodoList = ({todos, toggleTodo, toggleGot}) => (
    <View style={{ padding: 20, flexDirection: 'column' }}>
        {todos.map(todo => 
            <TouchableOpacity key={todo.id} onPress={() => 
                toggleTodo(todo.id)}>
                <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                    <Text style={{
                        fontSize: 24,
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0, .02)',
                        borderRadius: 10,
                    }}>
                        {todo.text}  {' '}
                    </Text>
                    <Text style={{
                        fontSize: 14,
                        textAlignVertical: 'center',
                    }}>
                        {todo.amount}
                        {todo.measure}
                    </Text>
                    <TouchableOpacity key={todo.id} onPress={() => 
                        toggleGot(todo.id)}>
                        <Ionicons 
                            name="md-checkmark" 
                            size={12} 
                            style={{color: '#de9595', padding: 10 }} 
                        />
                    </TouchableOpacity>

                </View>
                    {
                        todo.completed ? todo.note : null
                    }
                </Text> 
            </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
    </View>
)


// ACTIONCREATOR

export const toggleTodo = (id) => ({
    type: TOGGLE_TODO,
    id,
})

export const toggleGot = (id) => ({
    type: TOGGLE_GOT,
    id,
})

// REDUCER
let nextId = 0;
const todos = (state = [], action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case 'ADD_TODO':
            return[
                ...state,
                {
                    id: action.id,
                    text: action.text,
                    note: action.note,
                    amount: action.amount,
                    measure: action.measure,
                    completed: false,
                    got: false,
                }
            ]
        case 'TOGGLE_TODO':
            return state.map(
                todo => (todo.id === action.id)
                    ? {...todo, completed: !todo.completed }
                    : todo 
                )
        case 'TOGGLE_GOT':
            return state.map(
                todo => (todo.id === action.id)
                    ? {...todo, got: !todo.got}
                    : todo
            )
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export default todos;
```

Expected result: todo.got: to toggle between true and false
actual result is error described above.

Comment: to note toggleTodo() does work as expected.

Comment: Is it an action creator?

Comment: I will add the reducer too.  I didn't want to wall of code.

Comment: Long shot but, I should mention I am using Expo to compile it to my phone.  I know ive ran into a few errors that with enough digging found out it was Expo and Version problems.

Comment: I just realized I am not dispatching toggleGot()   ugh.  Rubber ducked myself.

Comment: thank you Edison.  I wanted to brush up on exact difference between action and action creator.. and that lead to me realizing that I forgot to dispatch the action.

Answer (score 0):

Opportunity I suppose to answer myself (ugh foolish mistake)
(heres a chance at that self learner badge this is the silver lining)

You have to dispatch the action.  Reducer will grab action and the state but it needs to be set in motion by dispatching it.

added that to my container. and works.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    toggleTodo: id => dispatch( toggleTodo(id) ),
    toggleGot: id => dispatch( toggleGot(id) ),
})
```